# How can I align fullscreen images horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to scroll horizontally through some fullscreen images that are aligned horizontally.I tried to use float, display: inline-block and other solutions but none of them worked for me. Instead of aligning horizontally my images stack vertically

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="./assets/img1.jpeg" alt="img1">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="./assets/img2.jpeg" alt="img2">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="./assets/img3.jpeg" alt="img3">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

body,
.wrap,
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrap img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: You have to expand html, body **x** times each image to stack them aligned. `html, body{width:500%}`

Comment: Instead of `float` or `inline-block`, use `flexbox`, it completely changed the game for me. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use flex for this solution:

```
.wrap {
  width: 500%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS in your code

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
.a,.b {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.a {
background-image: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/2wqv7fd.jpg);
}
.b {
background-image: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/2lborxv.jpg);
}
```

this will solve your problem.